What would cause a process to hang in an MPI_BARRIER call?
I am trying to run an MPI Fortran code.  It works fine until it reaches an MPI_BARRIER near the end of execution.  I have confirmed with debug statements that all of the processes reach the call.  However, quite often -- not always, but often -- a substantial portion of the processes never return from the call.  They just hang.
Let me say that in the spirit of trying to present the simplest code that reproduces the problem, I wrote a short toy code that does nothing except call a barrier.  It runs just fine.  I have no idea, then, where the problem might be located in the rather large code I am running.
This seems to be a problem only with the Intel compiler and Intel MPI (rev. 2023.1.0).  Other compilers don't have the same problem.  Further, it doesn't show up at lower process counts.  The problems begin somewhere between 64 procs (which always runs OK) and 96 procs (where I am seeing the problem).  I want to emphasize that all the processes are making it to the barrier and calling it.
What could be causing this?

This really needs your code. Take your program, and remove section after section until you have a minimal reproducible example.

I feel your pain - these issues can be difficult to diagnose because they are intermittent and disappear when producing a reproducible example. I would check again that all processes are reaching the same barrier. Maybe your code has a barrier with a loop and some processes continued, or you have similar debugging statements that lead to different barriers. I'm personally not aware of a good reason why barrier would fail as you describe.

@Ross  "same barrier" Good thought.  But, alas, I made sure my debug statements were explicitly pointing to the correct place.  Thanks.  And thanks for the sympathy!

compiler and MPI library are two very different things. Is the issue specific to compiler+library (e.g. GNU compiler and Intel MPI works fine)? the MPI library (e.g. any compiler with Open MPI works fine)? or the compiler (e.g. Intel compiler with Open MPI also hangs)?

you can also re-implement MPI_Barrier() with a trivial algorithm and see how it goes.

When you say that the problem only arises when using more than 64 processes, are you running with 1 MPI process per core or are you oversubscribing the cores? And did you try playing with I_MPI_ADJUST_BARRIER?

1 process per core.  Didn't know about that barrier variable.  Will check it out.  Thanks.
